# Prove that a function $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is totally differentiable in $(0,0)$ and that $f(0,0) = 0$. In a previous exercise, I needed to show that there exists an $A > 0$ and a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x,y)| \leq A \, ||(x,y)||$ if $||(x,y)|| < \delta$. Showing this was easy enough, and is probably useful in the next part. 
Suppose now that $f$ is bounded and Lebesgue-measurable and let $\alpha < 3$. Then, show that the following function is Lebesgue-integrable:

$$ F : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}: (x,y) \mapsto \begin{cases} \frac{f(x,y)}{||(x,y)||^\alpha} \exp(-||(x,y)||) \qquad &\text{if} \quad (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\ 0 &\text{if} \quad (x,y) = (0,0) \end{cases} $$

I know that we can ignore the point $(0,0)$, since it has measure zero. Moreover, $F$ is certainly continuous, and therefore bounded on any compact set that does not contain $(0,0)$. This makes $F$ integrable on  any such compact set. The integrability of $F$ on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, therefore, depends on the integrability near the origin and "at infinity".

When evaluating at infinity, since $f$ is bounded (say by some $K \geq 0$), we can say that:

$$ |F(x,y)| \leq K\Bigg|\frac{\exp(-||(x,y)||)}{||(x,y)||^\alpha} \Bigg| $$

Then we can change to polar coordinates and evaluate the integral:

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int_R^\infty \Bigg| \frac{e^{-r}}{r^{\alpha-1}} \Bigg| \, dr $$

But how do I then show this integral is finite?

When evaluating near the origin, we can use the inequality $|f(x,y)| \leq A \, ||(x,y)||$:

$$ |F(x,y)| \leq A \, \Bigg| \frac{\exp(-||(x,y)||}{||(x,y)||^{\alpha-1}} \Bigg| $$

Then we change to polar coordinates again and evaluate the integral:

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int_0^\delta \Bigg|\frac{e^{-r}}{r^{\alpha-2}} \Bigg| \, dr $$

Once again, how to I show this is finite?

I can see a vague relation with the gamma-function, but I have no concrete ideas.

Answer (score 1):

For the integral near $\infty$, use the fact that exponential decay dominates any polynomial growth. i.e $r^2\cdot \frac{e^{-r}}{r^{\alpha-1}}\to 0$ as $r\to \infty$. Thus, there is a $R>0$ such that for all $r>R$, we have $|r^2\frac{e^{-r}}{r^{\alpha-1}}-0|\leq 1$, i.e $\frac{e^{-r}}{r^{\alpha-1}}\leq \frac{1}{r^2}$. Surely you can show that $\int_R^{\infty}\frac{dr}{r^2}$ is finite (and also explicitly evaluate it).

For the integral near the origin, use a simple estimate:
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\delta}\frac{e^{-r}}{r^{\alpha-2}}\,dr\leq\int_0^{\delta}\frac{1}{r^{\alpha-2}}\,dr,
\end{align}
and this is certainly finite since $\alpha<3$ implies $\alpha-2<1$. Even more explicitly, recall that if $p\neq 1$ then $\int_0^{\delta}\frac{dr}{r^p}=\frac{r^{1-p}}{1-p}\bigg|_0^{\delta}$ which is finite if and only if $0<1-p$ if and only if $p<1$ (and of course $\int_0^{\delta}\frac{dr}{r}=\infty$, so $\int_0^{\delta}\frac{dr}{r^p}$ is finite if and only if $p<1$).